# Oracle Query to Sort based on two columns

Tags: oracle

I have a table with below data

[image]

I need below output such that first it should sort based on COL4 and then group by COL1 and COL2 in ASC order.

[image]

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: The output seems to be sorted by col1 and then col2. Can you explain how this fits with your requirement to "first it should sort based on COL4 and then group by COL1 and COL2 in ASC order"? col4 in the result does not seem to be sorted

Comment: Still see the same ordering. Can you explain better what exactly do you need?

Comment: For each Col1 type, corresponding COL2 should come in ASC order, But between Different Col1 Time Stamp should be maintained in ASC order.I modified expected output accordingly.

Comment: Provide desired output as a text. It is not convenient to type your sample data to create you an example

Comment: Why is the row `1, 402, 12345, 9/10/2020 10:50` last here? Your text description is not relevant to this output